# jquery.get success function firing early with Hypnotoad and Mojolicious?

Tags: jquery, perl, mojolicious

I had a quick question about some behaviour I'm seeing in hypnotoad vs Morbo.

I have the following bit of jquery code which is triggered on an event.

```
alert('calling update device list');

    $.get('updateDeviceList',

            function (data) {

                  alert('In update device list');

                  $("div#devicelist").html(data);

             })
```

When I use Morbo the first alert displays, then once the result `data` from `updateDeviceList` is returned the second alert triggers and the `devicelist` div has its HTML replaced.

However when I user hypnotoad the first alert triggers then the second alert triggers almost instantly.

before `updateDeviceList' even finishes. Is that what it means by non-blocking?

Is there a way I can get it to wait for my data to be returned first before proceeding?

Many thanks.

Comment: can you provide a running example (Mojolicious::Lite)? This sounds interesting but I cannot replicate without more code.

Comment: also I think this question was missed because most Mojo users watch the [tag:perl] tag and not the [tag:mojolicious] alone. I will add it.

Comment: I'm not really sure why this happens, but i had similar issues when i ran hypnotoad behind apache and keepalive was set to on, KeepAlive off fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

You have to delay the function, jQuery has a function called  [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) which lets you set a count down.

```
alert('calling update device list');
$.get('updateDeviceList', function (data) {
    $(this).delay(1200).queue(function () { // Delay Queue will delay alert and update
        $("div#devicelist").html(data);
        alert('In update device list');
    });
});
```